# Handle the Camera in a Fragment

Tags: android, camera

Excuse me for any grammatical errors.

I would like to use the camera in a different activity than mainActivity.
I found this simple tutorial on google [Taking Photos Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), that says I have to use this function:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

But, this function works fine only into the MainActivity, in fact, if I put this code in a different activity I get this error:
Cannot resolve method 'getPackageManager()'.

Some ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the following code:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

Context c;
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Fragment yourFragment = this;
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    yourFragment.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

Override your parent Activity's onActivityResult():

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Then add this to your fragment:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //Do something with your captured image. EX:-
                 try {
                  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                  String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                  Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
                  int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                  String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                  cursor.close();
                  imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath))
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                      e.printStackTrace();

                }                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I don't get any error, but when I open the camera the application crashes.

Comment: Which error are you getting ? You didn't handled startActivityResult on onActivityResult() method. May be this is causing the problem.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object

Comment: tahsinRupam, thank you very much, it works.
I'm sorry but "Do something with your captured image" which is the object of the image?
For example, I have an ImageView (the id is SkimmedImg) I would like to put the image I've done into this image view but I don't know which is the object of the image.

Comment: Edited again. Now, your captured image will be set to imageview.

Comment: tahsinRupam, thank you very very much! Now where is imageView, I think I have to put my image view because if I execute your code, the compiler gives me this error: Error:(69, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable imageView.  I tried something like imageView img = findViewById(R.id.SkimmedImg), but it doesn't work in a fragment...
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: tahsinRupam, excuse me, I don't know why, when I try this application on my Nexus 5X, the photo lose the quality when it appears into the ImageView.
Application image (Image View): http://i.imgur.com/VunFaHF.png?1
Camera Image: http://i.imgur.com/wjJ2a4w.jpg

Comment: @RvGPredator, please ask a separate question. I'll try to help you as much I can. :)

Comment: tahsinRupam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330052/the-photo-lose-its-quality-when-it-appears-into-the-imageview

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, I don't know why, when I try this application on my Nexus 5X, the photo lose the quality when it appears into the ImageView. Application image (Image View): i.imgur.com/VunFaHF.png?1 Camera Image: i.imgur.com/wjJ2a4w.jpg

Comment: Late comment, but might help someone else - if you took the code from the linked android developer page, you might have used the data.extras.get("data")? Thats just to be used as a thumbnail.